# I am trying to solve this probability problem for my data analysis class and I need some help please.

Tags: probability, data-analysis

Tom,  a  university  freshman,  makes  one  to  five  new  friends  every  week,  with  equal
probability.  The  number  of  friends  he  makes  each  week  is  independent  from  all  other
weeks.
We consider two consecutive weeks in the following questions.

- Let event A be “Tom made a total of 10 friends during the two weeks.”
- Let event B be “Tom make more than 5 friends during the two weeks.”
- Let event C be “Tom made exactly 5 friends during the first week.”

(a) Are events A and B independent? Please justify your reason.

(b) Are events A and C independent? Please justify your reason.

This is what I've come up with myself so far:

P(A) = 1/25

P(B) = 1/25 << I am not confident on this one though

P(C) = 1/5

Formulas P(B|A) = P(B) or
P(A and B) = P(B ∩ A) = P(B) × P(A) To tell if events are independent or dependent

I got P(B∩A) = 1/625 and P(B|A) = 1/25

With these equations above I think that events A and B are independent and events A and C are dependent.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: Did you calculate $P(B \cap A)$ or $P(B|A)$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Yes I got P(B∩A) = 1/625 and P(B|A) = 1/25

Comment: Please show your work in how you computed $p(B)$.  See [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), 
specifically $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}p^kq^{(n-k)}.$  You would want $k$ to range from $(6)$ through $(10)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see your question, but I assume you are here to ask if your results are correct.

$P(A) = \frac{1}{5}$ and $P(C) = \frac{1}{5}$ are right.
$P(B)$ is not correct.

Denote $X$ as the number of the first week and $Y$ as the second.
We have $A = \{X+Y=10\}$, $B = \{X+Y>5\}$ and $C=\{X+Y=5\}$

$P(B) = P(X+Y>5) = P(X=1,Y=5) + P(X=2,Y \ge 4), + P(X=3, Y\ge 3) + P(X=4,Y\ge2) + P(X=5) = \frac{1}{25}+\frac{2}{25}+\frac{3}{25}+\frac{4}{25}+\frac{1}{5} = \frac{3}{5}.$

So $P(B)=\frac{3}{5} \neq \frac{1}{25}$

From the "$X,Y$" representation of $A,B$ and $C$, we can see:
$A\cap C = \emptyset$ and $B\cap C = \emptyset$, which means
$P(A\cap C) = P(B\cap C) = 0$. Because $P(A),P(B)$ and $P(C)$ are all positive, so $(A,C)$ and $(B,C)$ are both not independant.

And we calculate $P(A\cap B) = P(\{X+Y=10\} \cap \{X+Y>5\}) = P(\{X+Y=10\}) = P(A) = \frac{1}{25}$, so $P(A\cap B) \neq P(A)$.

As a result, $P(B)$ should equal to $\frac{3}{5}$ and every two of them are not independent.

Comment: This was so helpful, thank you so much!!

Comment: You are welcome